# Dúvidas em desenvolvimento de sistemas Desktop C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

estou começando a programar em c# e estou com algumas duvidas.
Gostaria de saber por onde começar, por exemplo:

Eu tenho um sistema desktop que utilizo em uma empresa, precisava desenvolver uma outra no mesmo padrão.
Tem por exemplo essa Caixa de dialogo abaixo e não sei como cria, pq não consigo importar a biblioteca Windows.UI
aqui no meu eu só consigo fazer a mensagem:

MessageBox.Show("");

Acho esse muito feio tbm.. kk
Com faço para deixa-lo como esse outro modelo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já tem algum código iniciado?

Comment: Pra falar a verdade não amigo.
Eu começando um projeto do inicio, se eu tentar importar essa biblioteca: using Windows.UI, ele fala que nao encontrou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comecei um projetinho no Blend for Visual Studio 2013 gerando a mensagem por dialog. Na tela inicial coloquei um botão sem nome com a inscrição "Teste":

[image: Tela XAML]

Feito isso, selecionei o botão e procurei nas propriedades do botão os eventos que posso colocar no botão. Fazendo um duplo clique em "Click", o Blend criou o evento pra mim conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: Evento Click]

Por fim, meu fonte ficou assim:

## MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Popups; // Não esqueça de adicionar este using

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Aqui crio uma mensagem de dialog e a exibo.
            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Teste", "Teste Dialog");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

O resultado foi este:

[image: Teste Final]

Comment: Eu consigo desenvolver sistemas que rodam em Windows 7 por esse blend?
E qual a diferença entre esse Blend e o Visual Studio normal?

Comment: Consegue. Basta usar WPF ao invés de XAML na hora de criar a aplicação.

Comment: O Blend apenas desenha as janelas e engatilha os eventos. O Visual Studio é onde será feita a programação de fato.

Comment: Eu Criei uns sistemas pequenos pelo Visual, a aparencia não é agradável, gostaria de fazer uma com essa aparencia do windows 8.

Comment: Você vai se divertir com o Blend, então. É um prato cheio como aparência. Efeitos visuais bem legais.

Comment: Amigo, mas dai como eu faço pra programar em si? tenho que importar para o visual?

Comment: Só abrir a solution dentro do Visual Studio. Aí você só poderá acessar a camada de Back End, sem a edição visual aprimorada.

Comment: Vc conhece algum tutorial ou video que explica esse basico?
Eu abri eles aqui, mas to viajando completamente...
No visual eu não tenho acesso a nada dessas coisas.. Tentei baixar alguns negocios aqui e nada adiantou

Comment: Sim, tem bastante material na internet: https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=xaml+tutorial+youtube&tbm=vid

Comment: Obrigado amigo, me ajudou mto! Vlw

Comment: Amigo, mais uma dúvida. Porque eu não consigo importar esse using: using Windows.UI.Popups ?

Comment: Importar como? Acho que seria o caso para uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Por exemplo, se eu quiser utilizar esse evento do botão e mostrar essa mensagem que vc me enviou na resposta. Eu não estou conseguindo.
Eu so consigo fazer uma mensagem -> MensagemBox.Show("Exemplo")

Comment: Melhor abrir outra pergunta expondo o código que você tem com os `using` que estão anotados no fonte.

Comment: Vou utilizar esse seu codigo entao. Obrigado!