# Iniciando na linguagem C#

Tags: c#

Galera, estou começando em C# agora e gostaria de saber o que eu preciso fazer para deixar meus sistemas Desktop com a msm aparencia do Windows 8?

Por exemplo a referencia:
using Windows.UI

Espero uma ajuda de vcs..
Abraço!

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57818/d%C3%BAvidas-em-desenvolvimento-de-sistemas-desktop-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Use o Blend for Visual Studio para modelar sua aplicação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj171012.aspx);
- [Use o Visual Studio Community 2013 para desenvolver o Back End](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj171012.aspx);
- Para fazer perguntas aqui sobre este tipo de desenvolvimento, utilize as tags [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) e [xaml](/questions/tagged/xaml);
- Veja também os Wikis dessas tags. É lá que colocamos informações sobre tutoriais, dicas e links de informações úteis;
- A "aparência" de uma aplicação Windows 8 nós chamamos de XAML. A aplicação deve ser criada como XAML para que você tenha acesso aos recursos visuais tanto do Windows 8 quanto do Surface e do Windows Phone;
- A aparência de uma aplicação do Windows 7 nós chamamos de WPF.