# Dúvida sobre os using no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, xaml

Eu crio um projeto novo mas não consigo colocar esses using como nesse exemplo abaixo.
Ele aparece como no outro codigo ai abaixo...
Me ajudem por favor =/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Popups; // Não esqueça de adicionar este using

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?        LinkId=234238

namespace App1
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Aqui crio uma mensagem de dialog e a exibo.
        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Teste", "Teste Dialog");
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
}
```

Ele começa como esse outro:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Teste");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Dê mais informações. O que acontece quando você tenta escrever lá para colocar o que você quer? Em que situação você está. Se você não estiver conseguindo usar o editor, você vai ter sérios problemas para fazer qualquer outra coisa mais complicada.

Comment: Só para ver se entendi sua duvida os using do primeiro estão diferentes do segundo? Se for isso você já tentou adicionar no segundo os using que precisa?

Comment: Estou começando agora em C# e gostaria de desenvolver um sistema Desktop. Estou meio confuso pq os tutoriais falam que é pra windows 8, mas é so para esse S.O.? Ele rodaria em um Windows 7?

Comment: @DavidSouza o meu projeto é o segundo codigo, o primeiro é um exemplo pronto que consegui.
Gostaria de começar um projeto igual a de cima, para fazer um sistema Desktop. Estou usando o S.O. Windows 7

Comment: @EmersonMoraes neste caso você pode adicionar as classes que são esses "using" se por exemplo precisa usar o link use a linha e assim em diante "using System.Linq;" se não for essa a pergunta por favor descreva para que possamos ajudá-lo.

Comment: @DavidSouza, minha dúvida é o seguinte. Eu trabalho em uma empresa onde eles tem um sistema aqui, o sistema da empresa tem o mesmo design do Windows 8 mesmo eu trabalhando com o pc com o windows 7. Eu gostaria de saber como desenvolver esse sistema, porque o visual que eu tenho aqui não sai igual, o design esta tudo diferente...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O namespace `Windows.UI.Xaml` está presente para o desenvolvimento de aplicações para **Windows Store**, por isso foi dito que só funciona no Windows 8... não há Windows Store para Windows 7.

Se quiser programar para Windows 7, pode usar WPF que é o que parece estar fazendo... pelo seu segundo trecho de código. Entretanto, o código pronto que você pegou não vai funcionar.

Mais informações: [windows-ui-xaml-namespace-is-not-been-supported-in-visual-studio-2012-for-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551495/windows-ui-xaml-namespace-is-not-been-supported-in-visual-studio-2012-for-window)

### Sobre a aparência

O WPF suporta temas (i.e. skins). Essa é a forma de fazer com que programas WPF fiquem parecidos com qualquer outra coisa.

Ai você tem duas opções:

- achar um tema já pronto:

  - nesta questão do SOEN, há inúmeras respostas sobre como estilizar uma aplicação WPF para ficar parecido com o estilo do Windows 8, mesmo no Windows 7 - [Making WPF applications look Metro-styled, even in Windows 7? (Window Chrome / Theming / Theme)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592326/making-wpf-applications-look-metro-styled-even-in-windows-7-window-chrome-t).
- ou fazer um

Comment: Amigo, mas se eu quiser desenvolver um sistema desktop com esse modelo parecido como o windows 8, o que eu preciso na minha máquina? Eu utilizo o Windows 7

Comment: Editei a resposta... Vou ver se acho um tema para WPF parecido com os Apps de Windows 8.

Comment: Esse sistema que eu utilizo aqui no meu servico por exemplo, a caixa de dialogo é aquela que ocupa a tela inteira como nesse link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57818/d%C3%BAvidas-em-desenvolvimento-de-sistemas-desktop-c/57847#57847 
Por eu estar utilizando o S.O. Windows 7, eles utilizaram esse tema?

Comment: Sugiro que crie outra questão "**Como estilizar uma aplicação WPF para ficar parecida com aplicações do Windows 8 (estilo Metro)**"

Comment: Blz amigo, vou fazer isso então.. Obrigado!

Comment: No link que passei na parte sobre achar um tema já pronto, tem alguns exemplos de estilos já prontos, inclusive de código aberto no GitHub... dá uma olhada lá, tem vários temas bacanas.

Comment: Sim, vou fazer isso... Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Esses *using* aparecem quando você cria um novo *Project/Solution* no VisualStudio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Eles são colocados automaticamente pelo IDE em função do tipo de projecto que escolher.

Para desenvolver uma aplicação Desktop você deverá escolher um destes:

- Windows Forms Application
- WPF Application
- Console Application

Aquele que mais se aproxima com o Windows 8 é WPF Application.

Comment: Se eu escolher um desses tres, mesmo assim eu não conseguiria utilizar o:  
Message.Dialog ?? que fica em using Windows.UI

Comment: Consegue sim. Tanto o [WindwsForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) como o [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602949.aspx) têm MessageBox.

Comment: Mas ai que esta o problema, a minha dúvida é exatamente essa. Eu consigo colocar esse Message.Dialog ao invés do MessageBox? Pq utilizo um sistema aqui que aparece e precisava fazer um igual!

Comment: Não porque essa classe é para aplicações Windows8. Para desenvolver para windows8 você necessita de estar num computador com windows8.

Comment: Mas eu utilizaria qual versão do Visual Studio?

Comment: window8 - VS2012; windows8.1 - VS2013.

Comment: eu tenho o Windows 8 em casa, se eu baixar esse Windows8 VS2012 ou 2013, eu consigo criar sistema Desktop para rodar em Windows 7?

Comment: Consegue desde que não sejam Windows 8 Metro apps. Aplicações que tenham aqueles *using* que você refere na pergunta não funcionam em windows 7.

Comment: Na empresa que eu trabalho, eu rodo um sistema la em Windows 7, e no sistema tem o design de um Windows 8, Igual daqueles using... é o tema ou foi criado no Windows 8?
Obrigado pela paciência

Comment: Se roda no windows 7 é WPF com um tema do género indicado na resposta do Miguel.

Comment: Obrigado Ramaral ^^